# How to replace symbol with other depends on its position in a word?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, if `a` is in first syllable and same word contains `i`, replace `a` with `ä`.

`Barfio -> Bärfio`
`Foobar -> Foobar`

Comment: It is not a clear question. Please specify what natural language it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
newword=word.split("");
if(newword.findIndex(letter=>letter=="a")<3) newword[newword.findIndex(letter=>letter=="a")]="ä";
newword=newword.join("");
```

http://jsbin.com/jufujumusi/edit?console

Or even more funny:

```
newword=word.split("").reduce((word,letter,index)=>word+(index<3?{"a":"ä","o":"ø","u":"ů","e":"ë","i":"ï"}[letter]||letter:letter),"");
```

http://jsbin.com/yibegiboyu/edit?console

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing word syllables is pretty complex job and pure regex is hardly a right tool for this. But if we may simplify the requirements to just "`a` followed by `i` somewhere in the same word", [positive lookbehinds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) is what you're looking for:

```
a(?=\w*i)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zOrjBg/1